# How do I get the support vectors data (the model file) when using cross validation in LibSVM?

Tags: svm, validation, libsvm

I have a problem with the output file when I use `./svm-train ... -v k`

When I use the parameter -v, the output file doesn't get created, but I need the support vectors data.

Is there a way to get them?

Answer (score 0):

In cross validation mode, svm-train won't generate the model. Here the relevant part of the code:

```
if(cross_validation)
{
    do_cross_validation();
}
else
{
    model = svm_train(&prob,&param);
    if(svm_save_model(model_file_name,model))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't save model to file %s\n", model_file_name);
        exit(1);
    }
    svm_free_and_destroy_model(&model);
}
```

As you can see, there isn't a call to svm_save_model when it goes into cross_validation. If what you want is to use cross-validation to find a good set of parameters you might want to check grid.py instead (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/#grid_parameter_search_for_regression)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I know that crossvalidation is useful because of generalization problem and i need good set of parameters, but i need the support vectors too, because i want to "build" the function defined in the maximum margin problem (dual form). I have an input of 2 dimensions and i want to print that function. Maybe i can put the code in the else block into if block?

Comment: I'm so sorry, maybe now i understand. For example, if i have a training set of 80 elements and after crossvalidation with k=2 (so 40 elements of training and 40 of validation) i get 95% of accuracy, it means that i have to train the svm another time but with random 40 elements and without the parameter -v because i have got a very good accuracy. It's true?

Comment: @mattia Yes, that's correct. But ideally you would have enough data to work with 3 different sets (training, testing and validation). Still, cross-validation is a powerful tool to have an idea of the generality of your model.

Comment: Yes, i have a dataset of 160 elements and i split it in 2 equal parts. The first 80 elements represent training/validation set and others 80 elements the testing set. So, i use crossvalidation, so i get information about the generality of my problem, and later i will train my svm with only 40 elements of training/validation set and i take them random!

Comment: @Mattia Yeap.. that sounds reasonable :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i understand how to use cross validation.

Comment: @Mattia Not a problem... anytime